# Is there an equivalent "attribute/tag" to MSUnit ClassInitialize in python to nosetest or pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, nose

[According to official python guide](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures) there is a way to do this. But it's not exactly equal due to it's not creating an instance of testclass, so there are a lot of code which I cannot reach in "static" mode. Which I need it's a Setup method but just once per class instantiation, similar to ClassInitialize in C# environment. 
Sumarising, my problem it's I have some configuration steps to be executed before test can be checked, but this configuration it's just needed once per test class. If I use setup method this configuration code it's going to execute a lot of times (depending on number of tests in current test class).
I know I could create a custom solution with a "global" flag which were checked before executing configuration steps, but I think this is not an elegant solution and my needs are widely covered in other languages and unit testing frameworks :)

Thanks a lot for your help. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `scope` argument for [pytest fixtures](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#sharing-a-fixture-across-tests-in-a-module-or-class-session) is what you're looking for.

```
# content of conftest.py
import pytest
import smtplib

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def smtp():
    return smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")
```

Comment: Thanks @DonKirkby, does anyone similar idea to nosetest?